# How to connect 4 PIR Sensors to a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gpio, pi-2, sensor

I'm having trouble connecting 4 PIR sensors to a Raspberry Pi B+. I have managed to connect 2 PIR sensors to the Raspberry Pi but can't figure out how to connect 4 of them because there isn't enough 5v ports. Each PIR sensor needs to be connected to a GND, 5v port and a GPIO. If I were to use a breadboard, how do I physically connect to it the breadboard?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @SteveRobillard Do I need resistors?

Comment: If you don't need them to connect the sensor directly to the pi why would using a breadboard require them?

Comment: @SteveRobillard sorry , someone told me to use resistors then and this caused the confusion . thank you so much

Comment: This tutorial may help https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-12-sensing-movement

Comment: @SteveRobillard http://postimg.org/image/z0cpv2493/ steve this is what you mean. I drew the layout of how I would connect it based on your description

Comment: It is probably a mistake in your drawing but the ground wire between the Pi and breadboard does not appear to be connected to ground. Other than that yes

Comment: FYI this is a free program that can make drawing circuits easier http://fritzing.org/home/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a terminal block and connect one side (each pair of screws - 1-6 in the image below - ae joined together) to the 5 Volt pin on the Pi and the sensors VCC pin to the other side (you can attach more than one wire to each screw).

[image: terminal block]

or a breadboard.

[image: breadboard]

Most breadboards have a pair of red and blue lines on the long sides. These are called the power rails and all of the pins in the red row are connected, likewise for the blue. Connect the 5 Volt pin from the Pi to one of the holes in the red row, and connect the Pi ground pin to the blue row. Then you can connect the sensors power and ground to the red and blue row of pins respectively. You may want to read this tutorial from sparkfun on [how to use a breadboard](http://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-breadboard).